# Rewrite rules for s3 hosted single page application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

We have a single page application that consumes data from a service. The resulting URL looks like:

```
www.domain.com/path/?query=my-awesome-page-title
```

We would like the url to be prettyfied:

```
www.domain.com/path/my-awesome-page-title
```

S3 is a requirement.

I believe the only solution will include Cloudfront and possibly Lambda, but since I am here asking... I am not entirely sure. So I put the question to you experts out there.

Comment: You want the URL prettified... where?  In the address bar after you navigate to `/path?query=...`? Or you want to be able to navigate to the pretty URL and have it rewritten?  What exactly is the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: When a users navigates to www.domain.com/path/my-awesome-page-title they will get the correct content and experience. Within the app structure, I can keep the query parameter - or not. // How are other single page apps (written in Vue or Angular) achieving this?

Comment: Here's one: https://serverfault.com/a/633571/153161 ... which I believe has a test bucket I forgot about... `http://spa-redirect-test.sqlbot.net/posts?this=works+for+me` redirects to `http://spa-redirect-test.sqlbot.net/#!/posts?this=works+for+me`.  Not sure if that's what you're looking for.  This keeps the query intact, bit doesn't rewrite it -- only the path, using S3 redirect rules.

Comment: Wait... are you *the* Joshua Levy?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to have a prettyfied URL, the easiest and convenient way to go is using AWS CloudFront and Edge Lambda URL rewrite in AWS Stack where you keep a mapping to your S3 paths. However currently query strings are not accessible through Edge Lambda, which will limit you to only rewrite the path of the URL.

If you need to modify the entire URL including query strings you can use
 - API Gateway to rewrite the URL
 - EC2 instance (Too heavy though for the purpose)

Comment: While you are potentially correct, I believe more information is required before we can say whether this will work with the current service features.  Neither S3 redirect rules nor Lambda@Edge in CloudFront currently has read access to the query string (only the path).  They can both *set* the query string in a redirect (this is actually undocumented in S3 redirect rules, but you can do it using `<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>`: match prefix `foo`, replace prefix with `foo?q=`, means `/foobar` redirects to `foo?q=bar`) but neither of them can *read* it.  API Gateway functionality might be necessary.

Comment: Michael, what do you mean by "API Gateway functionality might be necessary"

Comment: @JoshuaLevy if you wanted to do server-side redirects (without EC2) that involved reading/parsing/interpreting/manipulating the query string, neither S3 redirect rules nor Lambda@Edge can (currently) work with those, they only see the path... but you could do it relatively easily with API Gateway, which has access to the full request including the query string.

Comment: @Michael I have updated the answer with your input for further clarity. Thanks